# How to input a time range (i.e. 5-9) and convert it to 05:00 AM to 09:00 PM within single excel cell?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I've been bashing my head against the keyboard on this one, basically as title states:

user inputs 5-9 within a single cell, Excel then takes that input and formats it automatically to output: 05:00 AM to 09:00 PM

I've tried using Time() but it doesn't like getting its input from the same cell and I can't hardcode the cell as that's not what I'm looking for.

I can easily hardcode this with something like

```
=TEXT(A1*TIME(0,0,0)+TIME(5,0,0),"hh:mm AM/PM") & " to " & TEXT(A1*TIME(0,0,0)+TIME(9,0,0),"hh:mm AM/PM")
```

But while that gives me the output:

```
05:00 AM to 09:00 PM
```

It does not allow for any dynamic use. So is my request even possible and if so, how would I go about doing this? Would also take VBA solution to this though I'm way less practiced in VBA.

Comment: A formula can only calculate using a (different) cell reference, not calculate it's own cell value and update it. You'd need VBA to do this.

Comment: Why do you want user to enter into one cell rather than two?

Comment: Because the question on the script is "Preferred hours of contact" and I'd rather it be placed within a single cell. Most users enter it as "5-9" so I was looking at keeping that input and being able to format to it 5:00 AM to 9:00 PM. I can get away with hardcoding the AM and PM but that's not the main issue. I'm trying the format() function in VBA now and experimenting, its just rough.

Comment: Why not a drop down for start time and end time? You have total control over the input and it's understandable for the user.

Comment: Why is 5 assumed to be AM and 9 PM?

Comment: Usually first number is assumed to be morning as our clients are government workers and are not working a 24/7 shift. Most, if not all, federal buildings in America close in the evening, so I can get away with this in this particular scenario. 

I attempted a drop down menu previously, it wasn't well received.

I think I have it solved, testing in a little. I'm going to use InStr() to split left and right of the "-" and then format it the way I want, it /should/ work in theory. Will report back. Yay learning VBA.

Comment: Hahahaha I try really hard to keep researching the issue myself, always learn. It's good not to put all my eggs in one basket in case I fail, but I'll never stop trying to figure out the puzzle :) Thanks!

Comment: A VBA Worksheet Changed function would be easy to write.

Comment: What are you referring to Jerry? Can you give me an example? I'm learning vba as time allows but I'd love to see an example of this changed function.